# Calling a php script from another php script through URL

Tags: php, url

I have a php script `converter.php` that takes in `$values['abc']` and `$filetoWrite` as inputs from a URL.
I'm redirecting to this php script from `source.php`

This doesn't seem to work.

```
header('Location: converter.php?abc='.$values['abc'].'&filetoWrite='.$fileToWrite);
```

Is there another way to do this.
`converter.php` is in the same path

how do I make sure that I don't redirect but run that URL and stay in the same php script –

Comment: `This doesn't seem to work.` means? What is the error you get?

Comment: `This doesn't seem to work.` what exactly happens?

Comment: I don't get anything as error.. The values aren't posted.. echo $values['abc'] and echo $filetowrite produces right results

Comment: If I run converter.php on as a URL on web browser with the same 2 values, it works fine

Comment: This is not calling another php, this is redirecting. You're not?

Comment: I'm sorry.. redirecting..

Comment: `header` is used for redirection.

Comment: Gotcha! how do I make sure that I don't redirect but run that URL and stay in the same php script

Comment: I want to run that url converter.php without redirecting

Comment: @Ankur For staying on same page without redirection use `AJAX` for calling `converter.php` from `source.php`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar something simpler.. Will file_get_contents work? just googled it

Comment: @Ankur Yeah....:) It will but if `allow_url_fopen` is disallowed in your server than `file_get_contents` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a number of ways `"getting"` the results of a PHP page:

- [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), but you will need `"allow_url_fopen"` in *php.ini* for that.. 
  Thats the most simplest of all.
- [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
- [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)
- [`fopen/fread/fclose`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), the old good ones.

what to use is mostly what your server *provides*.

checking with etc. `function_exists("curl_init");` is needed.